# How can I install MySql using InnoSetup?

Tags: mysql, inno-setup, windows

I have Windows Application created in .Net Framework 4.5 , and i have created the setup using the InnoSetup but i want to install MySql in client machine as well if it is not installed in his machine.

Please provide the solution.